# Submit Form return HTTP ERROR 400 for logged in User with non DefaultAuthenticateScheme

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building MVC Core app that has multiple logins for different users:

1. CMSUsers.
2. ClientUsers

Each Users' type is stored in different sql server table.
As I am using **Cookie Authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity**, I created the following schemes:

1. CMS
2. Client

I have registered the schemes in the Startup.cs file as:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    services.AddAuthentication("CMS")
        .AddCookie("CMS", o => { o.LoginPath = "/CMS/Login"; })
        .AddCookie("Client", o => { o.LoginPath = "/Client/Login"; });

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

I have decorated Controller Actions with its shceme and required Role as needed:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Client", Roles = "AdminRole")]
```

Some Actions are not decorated with Authorize as they are used by all users (Logged in or Logged out).

**The Problem:**
When any  of the Users' type (CMS or Client, wether they are logged in or not) try to submiting a simple form:

```
<form action="/Home/Search" method="post">
  <div class="input-group">
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Search"  value="">
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

and the target actions is:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Search(SearchViewModel vm)
{
    vm.Results = ""; //Do some work
    return View("Search", vm);
}
```

only **CMSUsers** manage to reach the target action, because **CMS scheme** is the **default scheme** as registered in Startup.cs:

```
    services.AddAuthentication("CMS")
        .AddCookie("CMS", o => { o.LoginPath = "/CMS/Login"; })
        .AddCookie("Client", o => { o.LoginPath = "/Client/Login"; });
```

If I change the **default scheme** to **Client**, only **Client Scheme** will manage to call the target action and **CMS** will get error 400.

Also, if I remove the **[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]** from the target action, all users can submit the form successfully.

What am I missing?

Or is it a single scheme authentication only?

Comment: You could just put a Authorize attribute for the Search method, then this will allow all the user who has authenticated could access this method.

Comment: Search method has to be available for non logged in users. So I can not decorate it with Authorize attribute. Thanks Brando Zhang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the web, adding the following to the Startup.cs solved the problem.

```
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal();
        var result1 = await context.AuthenticateAsync("CMS");
        if (result1?.Principal != null)
        {
            principal.AddIdentities(result1.Principal.Identities);
        }

        var result2 = await context.AuthenticateAsync("Client");
        if (result2?.Principal != null)
        {
            principal.AddIdentities(result2.Principal.Identities);
        }

        context.User = principal;
        await next();
    });
```